# Jumpy touchpad in Thinkpad T460s ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, lenovo

I just bought T460s and installed 16.04. The touchpad is very very jumpy.  Pointer moves here and there all the time. I have tried all the solutions available like using libinput, etc. Has anyone faced this problem ? Please suggest the solution.

Comment: does it behave badly al the time or just when it's connected to to power? I have ThinkPadt460p and I have this issue just when connected to power source, I think it is related to grounding.

Comment: It happens all the time. I returned this laptop.